# SQLite android query() / like com acentos e sem

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, acentuação

Como fazer uma *query* no SQLite para Android que busque tanto palavras acentuadas e não acentuadas?

Por exemplo:

```
String[]ARGUMENTOS = {"%"+argumento+"%"}

query(TABELA_CIDADES, COLUNA_NOME, NOME + " like ?",ARGUMENTOS,null,null,null,null);
```

Onde o argumento para a busca seria Sao Paulo, sem acento, mas que buscasse também São Paulo, e vice versa.

Vi em algumas perguntas e na internet, que muitas pessoas recomendam criar uma coluna normalizada com os nomes sem acento e realizar a busca em ambas, mas queria saber se existe alguma outra opção.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

A solução apresentada até funciona, mas é absurda.

O SQLite trabalha bem por padrão com ASCII e deixa o usuário se virar com outras opções. Se vai usar acento precisa de outra codificação de texto.

Uma hipótese é usar o UTF-8 que as pessoas consideram universal (há controvérsias), mas ela tem um problema, o código necessário para lidar com UTF-8 correto é absurdamente maior que o próprio SQLite.

Uma alternativa é usar UTF-16 (na verdade UCS-2) que fará o tamanho dos dados ficarem grandes. Para implementar um *collate* adequado para esta codificação não ficará tão simples também. Haverá algum ganho de performance, mas não sei se compensa, na maior parte das vezes quase compensa usar a solução da pergunta.

O SQLite diz que suporta ambos , claro que ele suporta qualquer coisa, mas isto não quer dizer que possui o *collate* apropriado por padrão. [Tem uma extensão](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18) ([ICU extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt)), ou pode usar o que a linguagem oferece, mas raramente esta é uma opção viável.

Outra possibilidade é usar uma codificação Latin1 (ISO 8859-1). Ela é bem mais simples, tão rápida quanto dá para ser onde tem acentos e não ocupa espaço extra, mas precisa se virar com a extensão, nunca vi uma pronta.

Se quiser fazer algo mais simples tem uma [pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1785/101) que eu fiz e a resposta do Bacco resolve o problema em 99% dos casos, para algumas pessoas só esses casos contam.

Dito tudo isto :P, a implementação do SQLite no [Android possui a capacidade de fazer isto](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), para funcionar deve usar a opção de `COLLATE LOCALIZED`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: bigown, muito completa a sua resposta, porém sou iniciante no android e acho que não compreendi completamente. Você está dizendo que devo criar uma nova collation, como respondido na pergunta que você realizou, ou devo simplesmente utilizar COLLATE LOCALIZED? Se for somente o COLLATE LOCALIZED devo passá-lo como o parâmetro orderBy do método query() ou devo adicionar algo à tabela do banco de dados?

Comment: Você pode só usar o `COLLATE LOCALIZED`, só se não funcionar como deseja (não desista no primeiro problema) deve tentar as outras possibilidades. Eu acho ideal criar tabelas já com `COLLATE`, mas pode usar nas *queires* se a tabela não foi criada com essa possibilidade.

Comment: Estou testando aqui diretamente na query, porém não tive nenhum sucesso, vou testar utilizando diretamente na tabela.

Comment: Usando o `COLLATE LOCALIZED` diretamente na tabela funcionou, porém somente em query's onde utilizo comparção =, nas que busco utilizando `like ?` ainda não tive sucesso.

Comment: É, pode ter alguma particularidade da implementação que eu desconheço, mas faz sentido ter que mexer na tabela. Eu achei que poderia não funcionar com o `LIKE`, estas soluções não costumam ser completas. Não posso garantir que não tem outro jeito de fazer funcionar desta forma porque não uso o SQLite no Android, mas talvez tenha que aplicar uma das outras soluções, que não são tão simples de aplicar, vai ter que estudar a API do SQLite em si. Nem sei como aplica isto no Android. Por isso eu passei algumas informações de como fazer "na mão".

Comment: Vou continuar tentando aqui, assim que tiver uma solução posto aqui.