# Como ignorar acentos numa consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3, acentuação

Como eu poderia efetuar uma *query* ignorando palavras com letras que contém acentos? Exemplo de palavras:

```
Olá, é, Lógica, Pão
```

Tentei utilizar o comando `collate noaccents` da seguinte forma:

```
select c.* from Curso c 
where c.Descricao like '%Logica%' collate noaccents;
```

Porém, não obtive resultado algum, e só funciona se eu remover o acento da palavra `Lógica`. Sendo assim, como eu poderia ignorar os acentos?

---

### Exemplo mínimo

Comandos para criar o exemplo de ilustração.

**Tabela**:

```
create table Curso(Descricao TEXT);
```

**Insert**:

```
insert into Curso(Descricao) values ('Lógica de Programação');
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d0b598/4).

Comment: vc tem que linkar com a biblioteca de acentuação da sua aplicação. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1785/70 - note que deixei um código no final com uma solução simplificada.

Comment: Penso se seria duplicata até, apesar do titulo.

Comment: @Bacco vou dar uma olhada, mas me parece um caminho que não vale a pena, talvez eu opte por uma normalização criando uma outra coluna, terei que pesquisar. Eu pensei que era simples xD

Comment: simples é, só que é um caminho diferente do que vc pensou :D - normalmente ninguém usa o SQLite "sozinho", e a aplicação quase sempre já tem função de comparação, basta "linkar" com o SQLite

Comment: em especial, você tem a [sqlite3_create_collation()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html) (e suas variantes) que é pra usar a função que quiser para comparação, normalmente você vai apontar para a função nativa de comparação que já usa em outras partes da sua aplicação (até pra ficar tudo igual, o DB e o aplicativo)

Comment: @Bacco a outra pergunta responde boa parte desta questão, em um modo geral. De qualquer forma irei implementar de outra forma, vou deixar que a linguagem faça o trabalho ao invés do SQLite, assim é só linkar como você sugeriu. Então se você quiser você pode marcar essa pergunta como duplicata da outra e deixar a comunidade decidir, beleza?

Comment: Se vc achar que é mesmo, seu voto fecha na hora. Eu prefiro que vc pense com calma o que acha melhor. Sobre linkar, leia a documentação que eu falei, que é o caminho mais comum. Além disso, tem o create_function se você precisar de outras situações "accent insensitive" também.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [SQLite android query() / like com acentos e sem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110672/sqlite-android-query-like-com-acentos-e-sem)

Comment: @RBZ não é duplicada e sim relacionada

Comment: @Sorack retirado! ;)

Comment: @gato Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: @Maniero eu preciso acessar o banco de dados em outra maquina, a collation impede que eu acesse o banco usando um cliente, porque tenho que ficar recriando ela. Estou estudando a possibilidade de usar um algoritmo `soundex` ou similares, e criar as chaves para aumentar a precisão da pesquisa, mas estou estudando antes de tomar a decisão.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Eu iria por esse caminho: [Como fazer comparações "case-insensitive" no SQLite?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1785/101). É o **simples**.
- Note que algumas implementações do SQLite já possuem uma forma de lidar com isso, mas elas deixam de ter a maior vantagem do SQLite que é ser um código pequeno. Tem como vantagem lidar com casos mais sofisticados. Mas será mais lento. A pergunta não dá um contexto de uso. Falei sobre isso em [SQLite android query() / like com acentos e sem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110672/101).

  Se a sua implementação não tem algo pronto pode colocar uma forma completa de lidar com isso. Tem a mesma ou mais dificuldade que a anterior. Na prática precisa saber mais o que está fazendo. Pode até fazer uma implementação que fica do mesmo tamanho do SQLite [personalizando a ICU](http://apps.icu-project.org/datacustom/ICUData51.html). Será bem limitada, até mais que a solução anterior, mesmo sendo muito maior.
- A alternativa é criar uma coluna sem os acentos e indexá-la e usá-la para toda pesquisa (depois de tirar os acentos e tornar tudo minúsculo), e na hora que pegar o dado em si usar a coluna com o dado original. Isso ocupa bem mais memória e torna tudo bem mais lento, mas funciona. É gambiarra, solução de quem não quer fazer o certo.
- Uma outra solução é abandonar os acentos de vez e só trabalhar com ASCII. Eu acho isso terrível do ponto de vista de UX, e muito anos 80. Mas vejo sistemas funcionando assim até hoje. É retrocesso.

O SQLite é um banco de dados excelente, simples de usar no dia a dia, e performático, mas não é algo pronto, precisa de um certo esforço para fazer além do básico.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Me esqueci que o SQLite pode ter implementações diferentes dependendo de onde é usado, falha minha não ter contextualizado de uma forma mais clara. Irei editar a pergunta ;)

Comment: Marquei como aceito porque sua resposta mostra caminhos sensatos, e no fim adotei a terceira alternativa (é gambiarra eu sei `:(` ) mas "solucionou" o problema, ainda estou estudando a possibilidade de usar um algoritmo soundex no lugar dela.

Answer (score 1):

Só precisa configurar uma [Collation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) utilizando a *sqlite3_create_collation* e utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM Curso WHERE Descricao LIKE "Logica%" COLLATE NOACCENTS
```

Comment: E como configurar esse Collation? Poderia adicionar um pouco mais de detalhes de como fazer isso?